# RxJS - Using an observable in catchError block

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have 2 services `budgetTestService` and `budgetService`, I need to use budgetTestService when there's an error and budgetService when there's no error. The map() in the pipe of `budgetTestService.getBudgetService()` is not being called - `console.log('test service complete');`

Not sure if this how it should be done it kind of seems like I'm nesting and doing it wrong, am I using the syntax correctly?

```
this.budgetService.getBudgetDays(this.startDate, this.finishDate)
    .pipe(
      map(res => {
        console.log('get budget day server mapping');
        self.timelineBudgetDates = self.processDates(res);

      }),
      //map(res => {
      //  self.timelineBudgetDates = self.budgetTestService.getBudgetDates(self.startDate, self.finishDate);
      //})
      catchError(error => {
        console.log('error code running');
        console.log(error);
        self.budgetTestService.getBudgetDates(self.startDate, self.finishDate)
                              .pipe(
                                map(res => {
                                  console.log('test service complete');
                                  console.log(res);
                                  self.timelineBudgetDates = res;
                                })
                              );
        return of('some return value, maybe null, maybe a good default');
      })
    )

    .subscribe(res => {
      console.log('Response = ', res);
      //self.timelineBudgetDates = self.processDates(res);
      //self.timelineBudgetDates = res;

    });
```

The `budgetTestService`:

```
getBudgetDates(startDate: string, endDate: string): Observable<BudgetDate[]> {

    console.log('getting budget dates from test service');

    let dates = this.datesOfRange(moment(startDate), moment(endDate));
    //console.log('dates:', dates);

    let budgetDates: BudgetDate[] = [
      new BudgetDate({ moment: moment().subtract(1, 'd').startOf('d'), earned: 100, spent: 50, onServer: true }),
      new BudgetDate({ moment: moment().subtract(2, 'd').startOf('d'), earned: 101, spent: 51, onServer: true }),
      new BudgetDate({ moment: moment().subtract(3, 'd').startOf('d'), earned: 102, spent: 52, onServer: true }),
      new BudgetDate({ moment: moment().subtract(4, 'd').startOf('d'), earned: 103, spent: 53, onServer: true })
    ];

    const mockResults = function(observer: Observer<BudgetDate[]>) {
      observer.next(budgetDates);
      observer.error('...');
      observer.complete;
    };
    const update = new Observable(mockResults).pipe(
      catchError((error: any) => Observable.throw(error))
    );
    return update;
  }
```

**Output:**
Doesn't include: `test service complete`

```
error code running
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, …}
getting budget dates from test service
Response =  some return value, maybe null, maybe a good default
```

Comment: what do you need to call first to detect success/ error?

Answer (score 1):

RxJS observable chain would be executed only when subscribed to. So the issue behind output not including `test service complete` is that you never subscribe to the test service call. Particularly issue is here:

```js
catchError(error => {
  self.budgetTestService.getBudgetDates(self.startDate, self.finishDate)
    .pipe(
      // ...
    );

  // RETURNING OTHER OBSERVABLE HERE
  return of('some return value, maybe null, maybe a good default');
})
// ...
.subscribe(console.log)
```

Here you call `budgetTestService`, but its Observable is never subscribed to.
Compare it to:

```js
catchError(error => {
  return self.budgetTestService.getBudgetDates(self.startDate, self.finishDate)
    .pipe(
      // ...
    );
})
// ...
.subscribe(console.log)
```

In the latter code sample we return observable from `budgetTestService` that will be part of subscription chain.

Check this little example here to compare: ["async error handler in RxJS"](https://thinkrx.io/gist/65d073b7f78173f5cc49118087187a35)

Hope this helps